# Network interface receives no frames unless in promiscuous mode

Tags: linux, networking

I have a network interface that refuses to receive traffic destined for it (destination MAC is equal to the interface's configured hw address).

Here is the driver info;

```
# ethtool -i eth0
driver: ixgbe
version: 4.0.1-k
firmware-version: 0x80000534
expansion-rom-version:
bus-info: 0000:04:00.0
supports-statistics: yes
supports-test: yes
supports-eeprom-access: yes
supports-register-dump: yes
supports-priv-flags: no
```

As soon as I enter `ifconfig eth0 promisc` the interface will start receiving frames. A tcpdump shows that the destination MAC does indeed line up with the interface's configure MAC address.

```
# ifconfig eth0
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:01:02:03:04:05
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING PROMISC SLAVE MULTICAST  MTU:1508  Metric:1
          RX packets:600363 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:230866 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:904700278 (862.7 MiB)  TX bytes:16161664 (15.4 MiB)
```

Why does the interface need to be promiscuous?

Comment: Did you check if there is only one mac address ? maybe another interface on your network does have the same ip/mac address ?

Comment: Please add to the question the outputs of `ifconfig` and/or `ip link` and  `uname -r` ; do you have VLANs?

Comment: There are no VLANs configured on this interface, although the traffic is VLAN tagged.

Comment: Please do not mask the first 3 bytes of the MAC in the question, you surely have it not as 00:01:02:03:04:05? ; also try to post the ifconfig without having the interface in promisc mode. Please add also `uname -r `.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I read through the ixgbe driver source in the search for answers.

As far as I can ascertain this driver utilizes hardware VLAn filtering (it has been suggested on some support tickets that reasons include security and performance).

This behavior is controlled via the IXGBE_VLNCTRL_VFE VLAN control flag.

The two options for successfully traversing these filters into the kernel are:

- Enable promiscuous mode on the interface
- Add a VLAN (e.g. using vconfig) to the interface